# For pose estimation, what is the typical range of the rotation values that are estimated? Is it from -180 to 180 degrees?

Tags: computer-vision, pose

I am currently working with the Rutgers APC 2015 data set for pose estimation, and see that the pose estimates, specifically the rotation estimates, have seemingly been rescaled to range between -1 and 1. Does anyone know if these values were arrived at by dividing by 180?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether they are in radians. Most algorithms use radians for pose estimation.

Answer (score 1):

The range between -1 or +1 is a normalized range like you said. The question is the following: Were those values divided by 180 (degrees) or 2*pi (radians)? You should check any existant documentation regarding Rutgers APC 2015. Usually, the convention is to have the angles bounded between -pi/pi or -180/180, because expressions like atan2 or atan2d returns angles in that range. The range 0-360 might lead to tricky bugs to catch and error during the 360,0 crossover.